# Does anyone have an example WiX .wxs file where a new MySql user is created and then a database is created?

Tags: sql, wix

I think my question says it all.
I've been trying to learn from:
http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson7.php#7.1

but it doesn't seem to have the case of creating a new database user. I learn best by example, so if anyone has an example to share, I'd be very appreciative!!

-Adeena

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported directly by WiX. I'm not sure if there is a setup authoring tool which offers direct support for this. Most of them allow you to create only Windows user accounts.

To create a MySql user you can write a [custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/authoring_custom_actions.htm) using custom code. You can use an EXE or a DLL.